# App Slicing Thinning: Pre determine actual true size & space taken by App install or update on iOS Device?

Tags: ios, itunes, ios-appstore, disk-space

Note: This has to do with **App Slicing** and **App Thinning** that was introduced by Apple in late 2015. Nothing to do with your 2012 question.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html

http://www.imore.com/app-thinning-ios-9-explained

http://www.macrumors.com/2015/10/05/ios-9-app-slicing-now-available/

http://www.appcoda.com/app-thinning/

Given that my iOS storage has been running out of space, I try to keep iOS App versions which are smaller in size and not update unless essential or compelled to {e.g. Uber compels updates}

So, I recently did a comparative analysis for 2 apps and what sizes (in MB) they show in 3 places (iTunes 12.3.3 On Windows 8.1 x 64):

**App Names:**
Todoist  11.0.3
Wunderlist 3.4.3

---

**Current Latest Versions updated & synced this weekend:**

**iTunes > AppStore** | As shown on AppStore before download
70
95

**iTunes > My Apps**  | As shown in iTunes after download
34
53

**iPad 2 - iOS 9.0.2 >** | As seen under iTunes > Sync > App Selection area after Install/ Sync
65
87

**iPhone 5 - iOS 9.0.2 >** | As seen under iTunes > Sync > App Selection area after Install/ Sync
XX
YY
{Will post these numbers soon as well}

I cannot understand why the "**complete un-thinned App from the AppStore** would *take more space* when **thinned for the iPad or iPhone**"

---

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How much free space do I need to install an app update?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49562/how-much-free-space-do-i-need-to-install-an-app-update)

Comment: Things have changed with recent iOS releases and application thinning, so I don't think it's a duplicate as such (answers might be different this time round).

Comment: @AndrewLarsson - This has to do with App Slicing and App Thinning that was introduced in late 2015. Nothing to do with your 2012 question.

Answer (score 1):

I can see multiple reasons for that happening:

**A) Compression**

Apps are downloaded in compressed form from the app store. It is similar to a Zip-file. When the app is installed on the phone, it is uncompressed by the app installer software on the phone.

**B) Differential updates**

If you already have the app installed, and are merely downloading an update for the app - you could be downloading a differential instead of the full app. For newer iOS versions, the App Store will calculate the difference between what you already have and the new version of the app, enabling you to download less. However it will still take up the full amount of space on the disk after the upgrade has taken place.

**C) App downloads after first use**

When you use an app for the first time, many apps will download extra data that is stored with the app on your phone. This could account for differences in app size as listed by the App Store, compared to the amount of space the app takes on your phone in practice.

Comment: @jk - I like the direction you are going but it needs more detailed info/ math. Is Itunes now doing Differential downloads between app releases? I dont think so. I have yet to see a single app download partial updates.. Every update has mean double digit MB downloads.

Comment: They claim to be doing so. See Apple Technical Q&A QA1779 where they  write: "When generating the update package, the app store compares one or more prior versions of your app to the new version and creates an optimized package for each that contains only the content that has changed between versions of your app, excluding any content that did not change". Some call this "delta app updates".

Comment: Your claim about block sizes is incorrect. Using statfs() on both my rMBP 15" (running OS X 10.11.4) and iPhone 6S (running iOS 9.3.1), the block size for the root filesystem on both is 4096 bytes.

Comment: I wasn't able to check on iOS right now, but you're right regarding OS X. I checked using "diskutil info", but I got the device and allocation block sizes mixed up. The allocation block size is indeed 4 kB on OS X, whereas it is the irrelevant device block size which is 512 bytes.